# How to compare two natural numbers in Agda with standard library (like N -> N -> Bool)?

Tags: comparison-operators, agda

I can compare two natural numbers by writing comparator manually:

```
is-≤ : ℕ → ℕ → Bool
is-≤ zero _ = true
is-≤ (suc _) zero = false
is-≤ (suc x) (suc y) = is-≤ x y
```

However, I hope that there is something similar in the standard library so I don't write that every time.

I was able to find `_≤_` operator [in Data.Nat](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Data/Nat/Base.agda#L27-L29), but it's a parametrized type which basically contains "proof" that one specific number is less than the other (similar to `_≡_`). Is there a way to use it or something else to understand which number is smaller than the other "in runtime" (e.g. return corresponding `Bool`)?

The bigger problem I'm trying to solve:

1. As a part of my assignment, I'm writing a `readNat : List Char → Maybe (ℕ × List Char)` function. It tries to read natural number from the beginning of the list; will later become part of `sscanf`.
2. I want to implement `digit : Char → Maybe ℕ` helper function which would parse a single decimal digit.
3. In order to do so I want to compare `primCharToNat c` with `primCharToNat '0'`, `primCharToNat '1'` and decide whether to return `None` or `(primCharToNat c) ∸ (primCharToNat '0')`

Comment: In the module you've found there's a proof [`_≤?_`](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Data/Nat/Base.agda#L156) that `_≤_` is decidable. You can use that instead of a `Bool`ean function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution suggested by @gallais in comments:

```
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; _≤?_)
open import Data.Bool using (Bool)
open import Relation.Nullary using (Dec)

is-≤ : ℕ → ℕ → Bool
is-≤ a b with a ≤? b
... | Dec.yes _ = Bool.true
... | Dec.no _ = Bool.false
```

Here we match on a proof that `_≤_` is decidable using the `with`-clause. One can use it similarly in more complex functions.

Suggestion by @user3237465 in comments to this answer: you can also use shorthand `⌊_⌋` (`\clL`/`\clR` or `\lfloor`/`\rfloor`) which [does this exact pattern matching](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/88dd1dd531ae309428cf4f6d3e4c6b69fc3a3ab3/src/Relation/Nullary/Decidable.agda#L23-L25) and eliminate the need for `is-≤`:

```
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; _≤?_)
open import Data.Bool using (Bool)
open import Relation.Nullary.Decidable using (⌊_⌋)

is-≤ : ℕ → ℕ → Bool
is-≤ a b = ⌊ a ≤? b ⌋
```

Another approach is to use [`compare`](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/3b7d1ecf3f396d947eab02ad89f8174fbbe3f7d4/src/Data/Nat/Base.agda#L171), it also provides more information (e.g. the difference between two numbers):

```
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; compare)
open import Data.Bool using (Bool)
open import Relation.Nullary using (Dec)

is-≤' : ℕ → ℕ → Bool
is-≤' a b with compare a b
... | Data.Nat.greater _ _ = Bool.false
... | _ = Bool.true

is-≤3' : ℕ → Bool
is-≤3' a with 3 | compare a 3
... | _ | Data.Nat.greater _ _ = Bool.false
... | _ | _ = Bool.true
```

Note that `compare`ing with a constant value [requires extra caution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708243) for some reason.

Comment: You can write `if ⌊ a ≤? b ⌋ then blah1 else blah2`, where `⌊_⌋` comes from the `Relation.Nullary.Decidable` module. I usually define a type class like [this](https://github.com/effectfully/Generic/blob/8a84f6af299627f20883ced05ae6ab17223f500b/Lib/Decidable.agda#L21).